# Simple navigation with hide/show hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, show-hide

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hBnXS/)

nav items:

```
<div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">nav 1</a>
                    <div class="hideshow">123</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">nav 2</a>
                    <div class="hideshow">123</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">nav 3</a>
                    <div class="hideshow">123</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">nav 4</a>
                    <div class="hideshow">123</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

css:

```
 #navigation ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #navigation li {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 30px 0px 0px;
    }

        #navigation li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000000;
            display:block;
            width:40px;


            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

            #navigation li a:visited {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000000;
            }


    .hideshow {
        display: none;
    }
```

js

```
<script>

    $("#navigation li a").hover(
        function (event) {
            $(this).find(".hideshow").show();
            $(this).find(".hideshow").css("background-color", "#808080");

        },
        function (event) {
            $(this).find(".hideshow").hide();
            $(this).find(".hideshow").css("background-color", "#fff");
        }
     );
</script>
```

any ideas why the `show()` function is not triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.siblings()` instead of `.find()`

`.find()` traverses down the DOM tree, and there are no children elements to the link

JQuery API for find ***"*** `Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.`***"***

http://api.jquery.com/find/

### Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hBnXS/6/

```
$("#navigation li a").hover(
        function (event) {
            $(this).siblings(".hideshow").show();
            $(this).siblings(".hideshow").css("background-color", "#808080");

        },
        function (event) {
            $(this).siblings(".hideshow").hide();
            $(this).siblings(".hideshow").css("background-color", "#fff");
        }
     );
```

Comment: yup! `siblings` it is

Comment: although, I will say, you probably shouldn't be using jquery for nav hover events, because when you go to hover the submenu it disappears. CSS would probably a much neater way to do this

Comment: @Rami.Shareef Take a look at this fiddle to see how to do this with CSS http://jsfiddle.net/hBnXS/7/. If you want to have multiple sub-menus you will have to look into having another `ul` instead of the `hideshow` div

Comment: @Rami.Shareef no problem. Also, if you know a website that has a nav you like, just hit f12 and inspect the elements and css to see how they do it. Can be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use NEXT or SIBLINGS, and not FIND to find the DIV which is next to the LINK and not inside the LINK(A) element. Here is the code, shortened as well:

```
$("#navigation li a").hover(

    function (event) {
        $(this).next(".hideshow")
            .show('')
            .css("background-color", "#808080");
    },
    function (event) {
        $(this).next(".hideshow")
            .hide()
            .css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there's no .hideshow elements within your link tags. Change your `.hover()` selector to `$("#navigation li")` and it will work.

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBnXS/3/

Comment: Hover works, the selectors are what is causing the issue

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. There's no .hideshow elements in the <a> tags. Updated my answer, thanks.